# C# - Creating new objects on buttonclick?

Tags: c#, variables

I'm learning some C# and in the tutorials, they usually put most of the code on the button clicks for the sake of teaching. For example, if they were going to show a streamreader, they would do:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader();
```

..inside the button's click function.

Is this a bad programming habit? From javascript, I remember reading a warning on some code I wrote that said something about creating a function inside a timeout event. Should all variables and objects be declared outside of the button click function?

Comment: No, its not. You can create an object inside a button click also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm learning some C# and in the tutorials, **they usually put most of the code on the button clicks** for the sake of teaching

The reason that putting code inside a click handler would be bad is that a click handler is specifically related to the UI, and the rest of your code might not be.

A stream reader reads from a stream.  Code that processes a stream should be grouped with it.  Code that handles the fact that you clicked on the UI has nothing to do with reading from a stream, so it should be separated.

Generally you should group your code so that parts of your code that are logically similar are together, and that parts of your code that deal with entirely different things are separated.  This will give you "high [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)".  It is related to [the Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

> Should all variables and objects be declared outside of the button click function?

Absolutely not.  If it makes sense to create a specific object when handling a UI event, do so.

However as I mentioned before, if you're dealing with non-UI things inside a UI click handler you're doing too many things at once.  Split out your streaming code into another method, another set of methods, or into another object.  This will make it easier to read your code, it will make your code have a better chance of being reusable, and it will make it easier to edit your code.

UI logic and flow is notorious for being kludgy and requiring a lot of work-arounds and special handling.  It is also the area of your app that you will get the most feedback on, so it will undergo the most change.  Everyone will have an opinion on how your UI should work, including non-technical users.  If you guard yourself against this by separating your UI logic from the logic in the rest of your app, then those changes will be much easier to make.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to write. There is absolutely nothing wrong with creating objects or calling methods inside an event handler method; the code you've shown is perfectly legal. But that doesn't mean it's the correct approach in all circumstances for a real-world application.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering more if it was a waste of resources, whether cpu or virtual memory, but based on the other answers, I'd assume it isn't.

Comment: @Walkerneo: If you're making a video game then that advice (avoiding calls to `new`) becomes more applicable because the garbage collector can make your game stall a bit.  If you're making a GUI app, then that is the least of your worries.  Long-running algorithms tend to be the place where you can make the best CPU/memory improvements and tradeoffs.  Those aren't something I'd stuff directly inside a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances within your handlers, this is common practice as everything is taking place on the UI thread within your handlers. In addition once the method completes that variable will go out of scope and get marked for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how long you need the object to live, if you wont use it outside the button event then it probably should be there so it gets garbage-collected when the event is finished, if you do need to use your objects outside then using a field in your class should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a bad idea to create instances in event handlers, but if there is any code that you may want to call multiple places in your code, it is best to that part of code to a separate method instead of trying to simulate button click events